# assign dynamically selected to option by select2

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to add selected dynamically to select2 via php on returned get variable but I can't figure out how to do this.
I was trying the following but I suppose this needs to be done with jquery.
`$grade` is the retrived get varible

```
<select id="grade" name="grade" style="width:125px">
        <?php foreach ($abs as $index => $a): ?>

        <?php $grade == strtolower($index) ?  '<span class="select2-chosen">'.$a.'</span>': '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $index ?>"
                    ><?php echo $a ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with this the other day, select2 has an option called `initSelection`. See http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation.

Here is an extract for the `initSelection` option.

```
// Or for single select elements:
$("#select").select2({
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = {id: element.val(), text: element.val()};
        callback(data);
    }
});
```

This will assign the default value.

Comment: What version of select2 are you using & are you using ajax?

Comment: I have couple of dropdowns and 1 is using ajax version 3.3.2

Comment: The current documentation should be OK then. Did this help you out?

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php echo $index ?>" <?php if($index=="condition for adding selected"){echo "selected"} ?>
    <?php echo $a ?>
</option>
```

I don't know when you want to add "selected", but you can add selected dynamically like this.